# Most efficient way to subset a dataframe according to matching values between two dataframes

Tags: python, r

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. I want to subset `df1` so that I only get the area-time pairs present in `df2`.

What is the most efficient way to do this in R? (Python too would be a bonus)

```
df1=structure(list(area = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), time = c(12138L, 
12198L, 12659L, 12670L, 12672L, 12719L)), .Names = c("area", "time"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df2=structure(list(area = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), time = c(12138L, 
12198L, 12266L, 12272L, 12284L, 12332L)), .Names = c("area", "time"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `df1[df1$area %in% df2$area & df1$time %in% df2$time,]` but there might be a smoother way

Comment: I think, based on what you are asking, something like this? subset_df = df1[df1.column_name.isin(df2.column_name.tolist())]

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency, `data.table` is probably the way to go--`library(data.table) #version 1.9.5+; setDT(df1); setDT(df2); df1[df2,on=c("area","time")]`

Comment: if the column names are the same as in the example, this is quick `merge(df1,df2)`

Comment: intersect, inner_join

Comment: Please wait until other solutions are posted, I bet that the datable one is the most efficient (as almost always) in terms of time.

Comment: OK I will but unsure as to why I'm being downvoted here.

Comment: @PierreLafortune now I see your comment, I deleted my answer (which is the same of your comment) do post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your example is representative of your data try:

```
merge(df1,df2)
  area  time
1    1 12138
2    1 12198
```